# How to use join statement

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

How can i do this with `JOIN` statement. I can't think of anymore logic to do this. I'm doing this because the `json data` is not shown because of that queries. Can someone help me to achieve this? First i want to fetched all the `enroll_ref` from `subj_enrolled` WHERE subject is equals to '$subject'. After that, I will now use the fetched `enroll_ref` to fetch the `lastname,firstname,middlename` to the `std_enrolled` where equals to `enroll_ref`. What method will i use to achieve this? Or what JOIN?

here's my code

```
if (isset($_POST['loadstudent'])) {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $section = $_POST['section'];

    $sql ="SELECT enroll_ref FROM subj_enrolled WHERE subj_descr = '$subject' AND section = '$section'";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $enroll_ref = $row['enroll_ref'];


      $select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT lastname,firstname,middlename FROM std_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$enroll_ref'"); 

      if(mysqli_num_rows($select)){
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
                  $data[] = array(
                        'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
                        'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
                         'middlename' => $row['middlename']

                        );
            }

          }
                       echo json_encode($data);
           }


}
```

Comment: Specifying what join to use depends on how you want the data. It sounds like an inner join would work best

Comment: @TimmyJim inner join works. How can i mark your answer as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `inner join`.

Inner joins return all data where there is a match between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an equal sign in your sql statement:

```
SELECT enroll_ref FROM subj_enrolled WHERE subj_descr '$subject' AND section = '$section'";
```

change to:

```
SELECT enroll_ref FROM subj_enrolled WHERE subj_descr = '$subject' AND section = '$section'";
```

Comment: That's not the problem sir. Sorry i just missed copy my code.